# Error occurred while parsing your function triggers firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement an image upload in react using firebase storgae and I run into err 'Error occurred while parsing your function triggers firebase' when I run firebase deploy in cmd. I can't seem to figure out where the error is coming from.
The error can be seen at the bottom of the code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});

const Busboy = require("busboy");
const fs = require("fs");

const gcconfig = {
    projectId: "abcdefgh-13ff0",
    keyFilename: "abcdefgh-13ff0-firebase-adminsdk-abcdefgh.json"
}

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });


exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        if (req.method !== "POST"){
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "Not Allowed"
            });
        }
        const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
        let uploadData = null;
        busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
            uploadData = {file: filepath, type: mimetype};
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
        });

        busboy.on("finish", () => {
            const bucket = gcs.bucket("gs://abcdefgh-13ff0.appspot.com");
            bucket.upload(uploadData.file, {
                uploadType: "media",
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: uploadData.type
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
               return res.status(200).json({  
                    message: "It worked"
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
            });
            return;
        });
        busboy.end(req.rawBody);    
        return null;  
    });   
});
```

**This is the error**

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

C:\Users\Joseph\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Is that all that is shown in the console?

Comment: Just added the error at the bottom of the code

Answer (score 0):

the error you're experiencing might be 1 of 2 things, but probably both combined...

1. The `keyFileName` file (abcdefgh-13ff0-firebase-adminsdk-abcdefgh.json) should be in your src folder so it can be directly accessed.
2. You should edit these lines of code:

```
const gcconfig = {

projectId: "abcdefgh-13ff0",

keyFilename: "abcdefgh-13ff0-firebase-adminsdk-abcdefgh.json"

}

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);
```

**TO INSTEAD READ:**

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')

gcs.projectId ='abcdefgh-13ff0'

gcs.keyFilename = 'abcdefgh-13ff0-firebase-adminsdk-abcdefgh.json'
```

// As far as I'm concerned this should fix the issue you're experiencing!